# undefined when iterating over an object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

An `object` is passed into my function. It seems to be alright when `console.log`ged, but iteration seems to be buggy (sometimes one element, sometimes two). I can't understand where the other elements are going.

My function looks like this:

```
console.log('Banks');
console.log(banks);

for(var prop in banks) {
    var bank = banks[prop];
    console.log('Bank ' + prop);
    console.log(bank);
}
```

[Result (log)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrXKD.png)

Comment: Mind explaining your problem in english? :P

Comment: I've always wondered how annoying it must be for non-English speakers to program being a lot of languages are in English.

Comment: Well that's how we learn English :)

Answer (score 2):

`for ... in` constructs in JavaScript are generally terrible. Using a `for` loop should work for you:

```
for (var i = 0; i < banks.length; i++)
{
    var bank = banks[i];
    console.log('Банк ' + i);
    console.log(bank);
}
```

Comment: if banks is an object I believe `for ... in` with `if(banks.hasOwnProperty(prop))` is needed to iterate over all the properties (if you want legacy browser support)

Comment: @PatrickBarr - you are correct. It's way easier just to forget about `for ... in` though ;) ... Or use underscore/lodash which does a nice job of wrapping all the weird browser behavior

Comment: Why do you think `for ... in` constructs are 'generally terrible'? - They are terrible for **iterating an array**
, they are super useful for **enumerating an object**. Their only bad thing is that the performance isn't too great.

Comment: It's object, not array (although I tried return as object and as array). Object.keys(banks).length return wrong number (sometimes 1 sometimes 2). Sorry for my english.

Comment: @sofdob - given the shape of your `object`, it should definitely be an `array`.

Comment: @Xatenev - You're completely right, I actually overlooked that `banks` is an `object` (although, let's be fair, it should by all means be an `array` the way it looks).

Comment: With array the same problem.

Comment: @sofdob do me a favour and try `var myBanks = banks.slice(); for (var i = 0; i < myBanks.length; ...` etc. (basically replacing all references to `banks` with `myBanks`)

Comment: `banks.slice()` return array with 1 element (or 2). =(

Comment: @sofdob - are you sure your input is always the same?

Comment: @sofdob also, is a `var banks` defined anywhere in a parent scope?

Comment: `var banks` defined in another function where this function is called (banks it's argument). 
`getBanksByMyCompany(...) {var res = []; .... outputBanksAccount(res );}  outputBanksAccount(banks) {  .... }`

Comment: @sofdob `grep` the source for `banks =`. Or, even better, put `'use strict';` as the very first line of every js file. I strongly suspect that someone, at some point, instead of `var banks = ...` typed `banks = ...`, leaking `banks` into the global scope.

Comment: @sofdob - you're in the browser, right? Open your dev tools and type `window.banks` into the console. If the value is anything but `undefined`, you have a leaking variable and a very probable cause for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[vzwick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961510/vzwick) is right: a `for...in` loop is generally not ideal because its default behavior is not what most people expect. In fact, `for...in` not only traverses own properties of an object, but also prototype properties. Look at this simple example:

```js
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function () {
  return 'Hello, ' + this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}

var person = new Person('John', 'Doe');

for (var prop in person) {
  console.log(person[prop]);
}
```

As you can see, `sayHello` is rendered. So imagine the result with big native objects which have tons of prototype properties... A big mess, right? That is why JavaScript has the concept of **enumerability**. `for...in` only considers properties that are enumerable. Therefore, if we do not want to see `sayHello`, we can do this:

```js
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
}

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'sayHello', {
  value: function () {
    return 'Hello, ' + this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
  },
  enumerable: false
});

var person = new Person('John', 'Doe');

for (var prop in person) {
  console.log(person[prop]);
}

console.log(person.sayHello());
```

However, a common practice is to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` like so:

```js
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function () {
  return 'Hello, ' + this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}

var person = new Person('John', 'Doe');

for (var prop in person) {
  if (person.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(person[prop]);
  }
}
```

Do you understand why your loop seems "buggy" now?